# Compare two cells in excel and return the matching number of Characters

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match, cell, letters-and-numbers

I'm looking for an Excel function, which compares two cells and returns the number of matching characters between those two cells.

I want the function to ignore case, i.e. A = a, B = b, etc.

Example:

**A1** = `abcdef` and **B1** = `Afcblm`.. **C1** = `4` (number of matching characters = 4 (`afcb`)

The function should compare all characters in two cells and then return every character which is present in both cells regardless of the order.

I have created the function below

```
=SUM(IFERROR(IF(MID(A1, ROW(INDIRECT("$1:$" & LEN(A1))), 1)=MID(B1, ROW(INDIRECT("$1:$" & LEN(B12))), 1), 1, 0), 0))
```

It does not work when I apply this to above example **C1 = 1** and I believe this issue is due to this function comparing characters sequentially.

Comment: Can A1 contain multiple instances of the same letter? e.g. A1=abacdef?

Comment: There;'s a typo in the formula above - says Len(B12) instead of LEN(B1). But it will still only compare letters which are in the same position, e.g. axbx and ayby would give 2 but abcd and dcba would give 0.

Answer (score 2):

this will work if entered using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, rather than just <kbd>Enter</kbd>

```
=SUM(IF(ISERROR(FIND(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("$A$1:$A$"&LEN(A1))),1),B1)),0,1))
```

You will know if it's been entered correctly because curly braces will be placed either side of the formula in the formula bar like this: `{=...}`

It works by breaking the text in cell **A1** into individual letters

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
```

it then performs a `FIND` to check if the letters can be found in cell **B1**, returning 1 or 0

```
1
1
1
0
0
1
```

And finally summing the array completes the process and returns `4` as required

---

**Update**
as per Tom Sharpe's suggestion - for case insensitivity use `SEARCH` instead of `FIND`:

```
=SUM(IF(ISERROR(SEARCH(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("$A$1:$A$"&LEN(A1))),1),B1)),0,1))
```

Comment: Nice answer. OP may want to change FIND to SEARCH to ignore case.

Comment: Thanks - I updated the answer to include this suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness this would be another way of doing it. It forces each letter in A1 to be compared against all letters in B1.

```
 =SUM(IFERROR(IF(MID(A1, ROW(INDIRECT("$1:$" & LEN(A1))), 1)=TRANSPOSE(MID(B1, ROW(INDIRECT("$1:$" & LEN(B1))), 1)), 1, 0), 0))
```

If you wanted to find how many distinct letters were in both cells you could use this

```
=SUM(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(MID("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz",ROW($1:$26),1),A1))*ISNUMBER(SEARCH(MID("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz",ROW($1:$26),1),B1)))
```

Both of them are array formulae and have to be entered with  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>